# Marriage puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I need some insight for the following problem:

> There are 100 girls and 100 guys. The girls each have their individual preference list for which guy they’d like to marry. Each list contains all 100 guys in the order of the girl’s preference. We’d like to match them up as well as we can according to their preferences. To measure how well we’re doing, we assign each match a number: the number of the guy on the girl’s preference list. So if a girl gets to marry her 2nd choice, for example, we assign the number two. We’d like to keep the sum of numbers for all the matches as small as possible. What is the number we’ll get in the worst case?

Due to the symmetry, the guess is that the answer is $5050$ which is attained at all girls having same preferences, however I am not sure how to prove that. I've tried both backward induction (how does the last girl choose, how the second last one does) and forward induction (what if there are only 1 girl, 2 girls etc) however no firm proof yet. I think the argument also may be of the kind: by deviating from the profile when all the girls have the same preference list, we necessarily decrease the number.

Comment: I don't get it. The $n$th girl to choose gets one of her $n$ favorite guys (since at most $n-1$ of them have been taken), so her score is at most $n$, and the total score is at most $1+2+3+\dots+100=5050$. In case the preferences are all the same, the $n$th girl gets exactly her $n$th favorite guy, since the top $n-1$ favorites have already been taken; in this case the total score is exactly $5050$. What am I missing?

Comment: @bof: I do not think that you are missing anything! All girls having the same lists must be a *worst case scenario* producing the worst score possible, namely $5050$. The *best case scenario* would then be all girls having different guys on the very top of the list, thus giving a score of $100$. That is to say: you solved it. Post an answer.

Comment: @bof: One thing may be puzzling, though! Your strategy suggests that the girls are arranged in some order and then choose the top-guy available on their lists one at a time. This may not be the algorithm producing the lowest score. That does not matter, however, since you were aiming for a bound on the *worst score*, not an algorithmic approach to finding the *optimal score*.

Comment: @String: do I understand your last comment correctly? We know for sure that the score of 5050 is attainable, so the worst case score can be only higher. But for any other situation we just make a choice as follows: the first girl chooses the best match, the second girl chooses the first (if available) or the second best match etc. The score in this case is 5050, although the optimal score can be even lower.

Comment: @S.D. That is almost correct. There is, however, no guarantee that any setup can be arranged to a score of $5050$. But the algorithm suggested by bof produces a score bounded by (not necessarily equal to) $5050$, still the optimal score for the given setup may be even lower.

Comment: So to sum up: Each setup can be arranged to reach a score bounded by $5050$ so all optimal scores are bounded by $5050$ too. On the other hand all girls having identical list will produce the score $5050$ (which is immune to improval as the girls can be interchanged without effect). So $5050$ is the highest possible score, and, it can be attained.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what "in the worst case" means. Does it mean the worst score achievable, or the worst score the given preferences could force us into?

Comment: @user2357112: it is certainly $\sup\inf$. In the description it is said: *`We’d like to keep the sum of numbers for all the matches as small as possible.`* Hence, given any preference profile we are minimizing. The worst case can only refer to uncertainty, and the only uncertainty here is in preference profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the preferences are all the same, the score will be $1+2+3+\cdots+100=5050$ for any matching. I claim that, for arbitrary preferences, we can always find a matching whose score is no greater than $5050$.

Namely, order the girls, and let each girl in turn take her favorite available guy. (This may not be the optimal procedure, but we don't care.) The $n$th girl gets one of her $n$ favorite guys (since at most $n-1$ of them have been taken), so her score is at most $n$, and the total score is at most $1+2+3+\cdots+100=5050$.